Operate both cameras of stereo camera seperately using OpenCV
I have a stereocam, and I want both cameras to work separately, so that I can perform camera calibration and other techniques to implement stereo vision. Code of displaying it is basic OpenCV ,if anyone wants to see.
Here's the code:
import cv2

def capture_dual_camera_module(camera_index_left=1, camera_index_right=2):
    
    """
    Captures video streams from two cameras (stereo camera) simultaneously.

    Args:
        camera_index_left (int, optional): Index of the left camera (default: 0).
        camera_index_right (int, optional): Index of the right camera (default: 1).

    Returns:
        None
    """

    cap_left = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index_left)
    cap_right = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index_right)

    if not (cap_left.isOpened() and cap_right.isOpened()):
        print("Error: One or both camera streams could not be opened.")
        return

    while True:
        # Capture frames from both cameras
        ret_left, frame_left = cap_left.read()
        ret_right, frame_right = cap_right.read()

        if not ret_left or not ret_right:
            print("Error: Couldn't read frames from one or both camera streams.")
            break

        # Display the resulting frames (adjust window names for clarity):
        cv2.imshow('Left Camera', frame_left)
        cv2.imshow('Right Camera', frame_right)

        # Break the loop on 'q' key press
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release capture resources
    cap_left.release()
    cap_right.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    capture_dual_camera_module()  

I have a stereo camera that works just fine when operated normally as a USB cam. But what I want is to control both modules separately. I tried it using OpenCV by passing the camera index. The problem here is that the webcam of my laptop has index 0, and  the USB stereo cam has index 1. When I pass indexes [0 1], it releases a webcam and stereocam. When I pass indexes [1 2], it shows error:
[ERROR:0@0.125] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

[ERROR:0@0.163] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

Error: One or both camera streams could not be opened.

This is the camera I am using

I expect that it may need to modify firmware in this hardware - and this can do author of this hardware

can you get a feed from these cameras with any other program?

What if you change boolean to if not ret_left and not ret_right: instead of or?

I used blue iris sofware to check and in that software both camera display a seperate frame.

using if not ret_left and not ret_right the error still remains.

Can I myself modify firmware? Are there any tools to do so?

I have experience on using that stereo camera. Processor on that camera will automatically fuse the result of left and right camera into one big image, making the stereo camera represented by only 1 index. To split the image, you can do
camera_index = 1

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)

if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Not found")
    return

while True:
    ref, frame = cap.read()
    h, w, channels = frame.shape
    half = w//2

    # left camera
    left_part = frame[:, :half] 

    # right camera
    right_part = frame[:, half:] 

Another tip:
Camera index sometimes will change when you restart your computer. So don't forget to check the index of stereo camera.

Not really it just divides the left camera in half and releases it. The main issue here is that right camera is not working and I don't know why. I used Blue Iris software and gives two seperate frames meaning that both left and right cameras are working but when I use openCV it only shows left camera result.

@AmeerHamzah could u also post what shown if you use : normal webcam app, iris software and opencv just to make sure?
